# "git --version" still showing the older version of git

Tags: software-installation, git, make, configure

I downloaded git version 2.9.5 to replace my older version which is 2.7.4.

I downloaded the .gz file from: https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/

Turned out as I tried installing that I was missing zlib.h header file, i installed it by issuing the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libz-dev
```

Then I navigated to the newly unzipped git directory again and did all of the following steps:

```
./configure
make 
make install
```

Everything went smooth and I did not run into any problems, but `git --version` still shows:

```
git version 2.7.4
```

Why is that the case and how to fix it?

**Edit:**

Thanks Yaron, the problem has ALMOST been fix. the last step:

> make install install-doc install-html

gives me the following error:

> "ASCIIDOC git-revert.xml /bin/sh: 2: asciidoc: not found Makefile:334:
>   recipe for target 'git-revert.xml' failed make[1]: ***
>   [git-revert.xml] Error 127 make[1]: Leaving directory
>   '/home/omair/git-2.9.5/Documentation' Makefile:2367: recipe for target
>   'install-doc' failed make: *** [install-doc] Error 2"

I have already, as suggested by "https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/solved-asciidoctor-asciidoc-not-found-in-path/10017/2" did these steps

> sudo apt-get install asciidoctor

and when that failed,tried:

> sudo gem  install asciidoctor

still getting the error but the git has now been updated.

Comment: Let's back up a bit. Why did you specifically choose version 2.9.5? This choice is oddly specific given that the latest version is 2.17.0. In any case, for ease of installation, I would recommend using the git PPA (https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) instead of installing from a tarball like you did.

Comment: I didn't know that the latest version is 2.17.0 and second I just wanna learn how to unzip and manually install in linux.

Comment: @edwinksl - in the link provided by the OP, the git gz binaries sort algorithm shows 2.9.5 at the end, of the list while 2.17.0 is in the middle

Comment: @LinuxNewbie can you check `update-alternatives --config git`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you have two versions of git in your computer:

1. Version 2.7.4 which was installed by `root`

   - You didn't remove the git version 2.7.4
2. Version 2.9.5 which was installed locally by your user

   - You didn't update your path to use git 2.9.5 instead of git 2.7.4
   - You didn't install git as user `root`

In order to use git version 2.9.5, you can:

1. Use the newly installed git binary:

   - Find in your home directory, the location of the new git binary
   - Update your path to find first the newly installed git 2.9.5
2. Install git as root (see info taken from `INSTALL` file in `git-2.17.0.tar.gz` package - please review the `INSTALL` file in source directory of your package for more info)

> ```
>            Git installation
> ```
>
> Normally you can just do "make" followed by "make install", and that
>   will install the git programs in your own ~/bin/ directory.  If you
>   want to do a global install, you can do
>
> ```
>     $ make prefix=/usr all doc info ;# as yourself
>     # make prefix=/usr install install-doc install-html install-info ;# as root
> ```
>
> (or prefix=/usr/local, of course).  Just like any program suite that
>   uses $prefix, the built results have some paths encoded, which are
>   derived from $prefix, so "make all; make prefix=/usr install" would
>   not work.
>
> The beginning of the Makefile documents many variables that affect the
>   way git is built.  You can override them either from the command line,
>   or in a config.mak file.
>
> Alternatively you can use autoconf generated ./configure script to set
>   up install paths (via config.mak.autogen), so you can write instead
>
> ```
>     $ make configure ;# as yourself
>     $ ./configure --prefix=/usr ;# as yourself
>     $ make all doc ;# as yourself
>     # make install install-doc install-html;# as root
> ```

Comment: I repeated all the steps as "sudo", but it still shows the older version. Edit: I even deleted the older version and re-repeated all the steps and it now says: "bash: /usr/bin/git: No such file or directory
"

Comment: @LinuxNewbie Your path is defined in a way it choose the older version of `git`, the simple way to use the git version you compiled is the execute `~/bin/git --version` - assuming that the binary was installed there

Comment: @LinuxNewbie - did you execute the command ` make install install-doc install-html` as root? (e.g. by prefix `sudo` before running the command)?

Comment: @LinuxNewbie what happened when you execute `sudo make install` at that stage? does it install `git`? can you use `git` without installing its documents?

Comment: Yaron, yes I checked my cli history and I did use "sudo" before ` make install install-doc install-html`. When I executed "sudo make install " It did install git and the new git is working because I get "git version 2.9.5" after issuing the command "git --version".

Comment: ....but the problem I have put in the OP edit is still there. Should I just ignore that?

Comment: Just realised "sudo apt-cache policy git" returns: "Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.3" LOL what have I got my self into.....